# Enable V8 profiler in WebStorm with an npm profile

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, v8, profiler

I'd like to profile my TypeScript microservice. I read that WebStorm is capable of this out of the box with V8 profiler.
I use to run my service via `npm start` configured in my package.json as `ts-node-dev --respawn ./app.ts`.

The problem is that the enable V8 profiler option is not available for the npm profile:
[image: WebStorm screen 1]

but only with a node profile:
[image: WebStorm screenshot 2]

Is it possible to use the profiler with TypeScript possibly via `npm start`?

Comment: Not possible with **NPM** run configurstion.
Try using **Node.js** run configuration to run your service instead of using NPM script